# excel upload with only specific columns

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, excel, excel-services

I'm trying to upload an Excel file to SharePoint, but i would like to only upload columns AL, B, and AU, and wondering if SharePoint has a way to do this, or if Excel has a way i can upload it to a sheet and have every other column get deleted and it shift the remaining columns together?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below. For the full article click link.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-an-Excel-table-to-a-SharePoint-list-d1c7a1e5-d9ee-4322-87ed-924323d0ac53

Works great. I have done this many times.

Export a table to a SharePoint list

1. In the worksheet, click anywhere in the table that you want to
   export.

   **Tip**: This displays the Table Tools, adding the Design tab.
2. On the Design tab, in the External Table Data group, click Export,
   and then click Export Table to SharePoint List.
3. In the Address box, type the Web address of the SharePoint site that
   you want to export the table data to.

   **Tip**: If you have already exported table data to this SharePoint site, the address may appear in the drop-down list, so you can select the address instead.
4. If you want to be able to update the table data on the worksheet
   with any changes on the SharePoint site, select the Create a
   read-only connection to the new SharePoint list check box.

   **Note:** When you create a read-only connection, two columns are added to the table so that the folders that contain the SharePoint list can be included. An Item Type column indicates whether a row represents a SharePoint list item or a folder. A Path column displays the folder path for a list item (for example, mylist/folder). When you filter the table data, you can filter within the specific folders that are listed in these columns. You can also sort the Path column to group all rows in the same folder together.
5. In the Name box, type the name that you want to use for the
   SharePoint list.

   **Note**: A list name is required. This name will be displayed at the top of the list page. This name is also used in the Web address for the list page and in navigational elements that help users find and open the SharePoint list.
6. In the Description box, you can type an appropriate description for
   the SharePoint list.

   **Note**: A description is optional. If you provide a description, it will be displayed at the top of the SharePoint list in most views, just below the name of the list.
7. Click Next.
8. Review the list of columns and data types, and then do one of the
   following:

   - If the columns and data types that you are exporting are correct, click Finish.
   - If the columns and data types are not correct for the SharePoint list, click Cancel, and then verify that the column cells in Excel can be converted into a data type that can be supported in the SharePoint list.

   **Tip**: For example, you may need to convert complex table data on the Excel worksheet to a simpler format, such as plain text or a number. Data types that are supported are text (single or multiple lines), currency, date and time, numbers, and hyperlinks.
9. Click OK to confirm that the table was successfully published.

   **Tip**: You can click the link to see your list on the SharePoint site. You can also view your list later by clicking Open in Browser in the External Table Data group on the Design tab.

Top of Page